# How to add an empty line after lines starting with a timestamp

Tags: centos, newlines

The log viewing experience is so bad in my current company. I want to add new line to the logs that I've trimmed for a specific time duration. I want a new line after every date-time.

The date-time format is like this.

```
2023-10-03 15:34:37
```

I am aware `tr` can do this but I'm not sure how. I'll select the answer best anyone who can tell me how to write that new to a new file. Because of performance reasons. I don't prefer using vi, I use less as a logs reader.

Answer (score 2):

In `vim`, you could do:

```
:%s/\v^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}.*/&\r
```

Note the `\v` for *very magic* so you don't need to add backslashes before every `{}()`.

Yes, `\r` in the replacement adds a newline (*splits the line in two* using the wording at `:help s/\r`), not a carriage return as one might have expected.

In [standard `vi`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) (`\d`, `\v`, `\r`, `norm` being all `vim` extensions), the equivalent would look like:

```
:%s/^[[:digit:]]\{4\}\(-[[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\{2\} [[:digit:]]\{2\}\(:[[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\{2\}.*/&^M/
```

Where the `^M` is entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and again inserts a LF aka newline aka `^J`, not CR aka carriage-return aka `^M`).

But the `vi` implementation on CentOS is `vim` (and has been since at least as far back as CentOS 4) so you should be able to rely on the `vim` extensions in `vi` there.

In any case `tr` is a tool to transliterate, replace characters with other characters or delete or squeeze them, it cannot be used here.

`sed`, `awk` or `perl` could be used (AFAIK, `\d` as a regex operator originated in perl):

```
perl -pi -e '$_ .= "\n" if /^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}/' your-file
```

To edit the file `i`n place. Or:

```
perl -p -e '$_ .= "\n" if /^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}/' < your-file > new-file
```

To get the result into a new file.

Or here, provided the `Regex::Common::time` module is available:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=time -p -e '
  $_ .= "\n" if m{^$RE{time}{strftime}{-pat=>"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}}
  ' < your-file > new-file
```

Which will do a stricter matching (not match on `2023-13-00 25:61:62` for instance). There's also a `$RE{time}{iso}` which will match those dates, but also many other variants of ISO8601 dates including some without date or time component, so can't be used here.

You can see the actual regex with:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=time -le 'print $RE{time}{strftime}{-pat=>"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}'
(?:(?:\d{4})-(?:(?:(?=[01])(?:0[1-9]|1[012])))-(?:(?:(?=[0123])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))) (?:(?:(?=[012])(?:[01]\d|2[0123]))):(?:(?:[0-5]\d)):(?:(?:(?=[0-6])(?:[0-5]\d|6[01]))))
```

Comment: I want to save it to a new file.

Comment: @achhainsan then just remove the `i` option for `perl` and redirect the output or use `:saveas` in `vim`

Comment: perl isn't very common in indian servers.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are one of the best `VIM` users out there. You helped me and a lot of others many many times before. Just wanted to say thanks for that and also wanted to ask if my solution is correct too / can be vimproved? :)

Comment: @Pixelbog. Thanks. I'm far from being a vim expert. Your answer looks fine except. 1) I'd clarify (like in mine) that it's vim specific 2) anchor the regex at the start of the line 3) (nitpick) maybe note that it moves the cursor.

Comment: vim isn't common on legacy servers!

Comment: @achhainsan don't worry, this also works in `vi` :)

Comment: @Pixelbog, none of `\v`, `\d`, `\r`, `normal` are in standard `vi`, but `vim` is the default `vi` implementation on most Linux-based servers, including the OP's CentOS. `vi --version` will confirm if your `vi` is actually vim

Comment: @achhainsan, "_I want to save it to a new file_" - then why insist the operation has to be performed in the `vi` editor? There may be better ways to solve the problem if you avoid unnecessary constraints

Comment: sure tell me sar

Answer (score 1):

#### This Command:

Press <kbd>:</kbd> and enter
`g/\v\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/normal o`

#### Explanation:

- `g`: short for global, executes a command on all lines that match a regex
- `\v`: Makes the regex *'very magic'* (actual name of it). Means that you don't have to escape special characters
- `/^\d\{4\}-\d\{2\}-\d\{2\} \d\{2\}:\d\{2\}:\d\{2\}/`: is the regex. Put it into a tool like https://regexr.com/ or https://regex101.com/, they explain it really good
- `normal o`: normal command executes arguments in *normal mode*. In that case it presses `o` which opens a new line

---

---

Read explanations from the Official Documentation:
`:help global`, `:help \v`, `:help normal`

Comment: "later" never comes. :D

Comment: By later I mean in around 7 hours. Have a really busy day sorry^^ But here rlly quick: `g` is the command, everything between the first and second `/` is a regex to match your time format and the `norm` command executes the `o` as it would be in *normal mode*. Sorry again^^

Comment: @achhainsan There you go, there is your (hopefully) good explanation :))

Comment: @Chris Davies Should I create a new question for doing it in either less(if possible) or on command line to convert and save to a new file?

Comment: I assume you know how to do that already. I was trying to point out that stating the requirement, lifting the restrictions, and showing what you've tried is better than statng the issue and saying it must be done with tools X and Y. Unless there really is a very definite reason for using tools X and Y, of course